# Save SVN auth info only for the session

Tags: svn

SVN command-line client on UNIX, saves the passwords in ~/.subversion folder. First time, the client asks if the password needs to be saved (p)ermanently or not. This can also be configured in /.subversion/servers

```
store-passwords = no
```

We have a few common logins where it is not desirable to save the password permanently. However, it is a pain to enter a password for each SVN command. Is there a way to save the password only for the session which is cleared out on logout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SSH-based Subversion connections, you can use public key authentication with a passphrase-encrypted private key and `ssh-agent`, unlocking your key at the beginning of a session.  Because `ssh-agent` holds the key in memory, when it exits, the key is no longer usable.

```
$ ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

Now a subshell is started where you can unlock your key and use Subversion:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_svn
$ svn co svn+ssh://svn.example.com/svn/code
```

When done, exit the subshell:

```
$ exit
```

The agent is now no longer running, and so your key is no longer available.

```
$
```

(Note that some desktop environments supply their own SSH agent implementation, and these may mess with the assumption that "exit" will clear the key—however, these also generally unlock the keyring when you log in, so your safety should be equivalent.)

I'm not aware of a way to do this with password-based authentication.  I suppose you could see if your particular flavor of Unix supports a `.logout` file or similar and attempt to script the removal of the password from Subversion's password storage, perhaps.  This solution has several disadvantages, though: you're relying on the shell to run your script, your script may fail, and you're writing your password to disk unencrypted.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I am missing some steps. SVN authentication is done here with user-id/password (with AD backend). I am not sure how to use SSH private key here. (There is no ~/.ssh folder).

Comment: You won't be able to use SSH public-key authentication unless you can configure the Subversion server to serve `svn+ssh://` URLs.  From the kind of server you've described, I don't expect you'd be able to accomplish this.  I'd say the last paragraph in my answer applies best--you'd have to see if you can use a `.logout`-style mechanism to clear the authentication.

Comment: Thanks @zigg. I have configured .bash_logout for bash shells and trap set for other shells. I will accept your answer as this solved the problem for now.